# How to properly set up a site map addition in a customization project

Tags: acumatica

I've tried to add custom site map items to a customization project, but it doesn't seem to work.  When attempting to add items, the list shows many duplicates of screens, making it impossible to tell which one is correct (do I select all of them?).  If I name the screens something unique and then add them, they still don't show up in a new site where the package is then published.  I cannot get this to work.

Is there a protocol listed somewhere that shows the proper way to add sitemap items to a customization project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a little tricky if adding new entries such as "Manage", "Explore", etc. entries as they all show up the same (no way to know which you need to select). It could be because you are not selecting the correct entries. If you select your custom page but the wrong parent entries I don't think it will show up.

I am assuming your problem is getting the correct entries so here is one thing I have done the past...

When adding non page sitemap entries, fill in the screen id with some unique values so you can find it later...
[image]

Then when adding the site map entries, you can find the entries by screen ID
[image]