# Site Map for Customization Projects in 2017 R2

Tags: acumatica

I have a problem with the site map in Acumatica 2017 R2

On version 17.200.0401, I created a sitemap and added workspaces and tiles. When the customization project is created it doesn't seem to include this information in the XML. As a result, if I publish this project on a new Acumatica instance, these Workspaces are not visible (although the menu looks correctly in the classic UI).

On versions 17.201.0043 and above, the situation is reversed. Workspaces are added in the customization project, but when I go to add the site map nodes to the customization project, those that are parents node (i.e. "Work Area", "Manage", "Enter", etc) are not selectable.

[Version showing the Parent nodes (17.200.0401)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrNaT.png)

[Version not showing the parent nodes (17.203.0029)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2pI6.png)

[Development instance where the new menu was created (version 17.200.0401)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E57jq.png)

[Target instance where it was published. Menu not showing the information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgRQa.png)

Comment: Did you include the parents in your sitemap in your project (as they are not included by default). If you created your own non page entries such as Work Area, Manage, etc. you can try to following this post to include them easier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46851342/how-to-properly-set-up-a-site-map-addition-in-a-customization-project

Comment: Thanks Brendan. Interesting idea about assigning a dummy name to the parent nodes. However, wouldn't this have an effect in the final package? Or do you remove the screen IDs and the URLs information from the XML after exporting it?

Comment: It looks like it is not yet possible to bundle workspaces in customization projects. I was playing with that feature last week and couldn’t find any way to include them like you can with the classic site map...

Comment: No you can leave the dummy screen IDs and the package will include and publish just fine. We have been doing this since the 5.0 package (now on 2017R2)

Comment: @Gabriel as Ruslan mentioned in his answer, it is possible. We had to delete our sitemap and re-add to get the correct workspaces to pull in (did this in version 17.200.0401). Looks like the version after you can use the Reload from Database option.

Comment: @Brendan good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To include custom workspaces into a customization project, you should proceed as follows:

1. add your new screen(s) on the Site Map screen (SM200520) - same approach as used with ver. 6.1 and before
2. add your new screen(s) into the new UI
3. open the customization manager and re-create all site map records for your custom screen(s)

Please be aware, with build # ***17.200.0401*** the **Reload from Database** button found in the **Site Map** section of the **Customization Manager** didn't add New UI elements into project.xml for previously added site map records. This issue had already been addressed in ***17.201.0043***.

When a node from the old site map is added in a customization, the following entities of the new UI should be also included into customization:

- Node in the new site map
- Workspace which contains the node
- Subcategory for the node
- Area for the workspace
- Pinned / unpinned status for the node (if it shared setting)
- Favorite / unfavorite status for the workspace
- Tile for the screen
- Workspace for the tile

Comment: Hi Ruslan, thank you for your answer

When trying the steps that you mentioned on the oldest version 17.200.0401, I saw that hierarchy of the the nodes on the Site Maps works just fine.

But on newer versions, it seems that workspaces, menu items and tiles  work good, but the hierarchy of the nodes created on the Site Map, doesn't look to function correctly. On the classic it is not possible to see these nodes.

On the other hand when defining the Site Map on the customization project, the parent nodes are not reflected neither added automatically.

Comment: Hi @DanielRendon, I was able to reproduce the issue with Classic UI SiteMap nodes on the latest 2017 R2 builds: *the Add Site Map dialog does not show Classic UI SiteMap nodes with empty ScreenID*. I have forwarded all details to our engineering Team and will update this thread once an approved build is avaialble to address this issue. As of right now, please use only build #**17.200.0401** to include your custom Site Map nodes into customiation.