# How to add "Manage" subfolder to Sales Order

Tags: acumatica

I have added Manage subfolder to **Distribution**->**Sales Order**->**Work Area**

[image]

The problem is that when I am adding pages to that subfolder I am not able to include that subfolder in the Customization's Site Map part and as a result the page is not being added to the testing system.

[image]

The version of the Acumatica ERP is 17.204.0019.
I have not this issue in the 6.10 versions.

Comment: Try adding a screen ID to your "manage" subfolder. It is a bug is some versions

Comment: @SimonML in that case it's showing error that it can't find the page and graph

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46851342/how-to-properly-set-up-a-site-map-addition-in-a-customization-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a ScreenID to your "manage" folder and put the default value "~/Frames/Default.aspx" in URL. This is a known bug in some versions